# How to trim right and left side a url?

Tags: python-3.x

I have list of websites unfortunately which looks like `"rs--google.com--plain"` how to remove `'rs--'` and `'--plain'` from the url? I tried `strip()` but it didn't remove anything.

Comment: Strip() is meant to remove whitespace, newlines, and whatnot from either side of a string, you're trying to find a substring within a string. What you likely want is some regex.

Comment: How to remove those 'rs--' and '--plain' and keep only google.com.

Answer (score 2):

The way to remove "rs--" and "--plain" from that url (which is a string most likely) is to use some basic regex on it:

```
import re

url = 'rs--google.com--plain'
cleaned_url = re.search('rs--(.*)--plain', url).group(1)
print(cleaned_url)
```

Which prints out:

```
google.com
```

What is done here is use re's search module to check if anything exists between "rs--" and "--plain" and if it does match it to group 1, we then check for group 1 by doing `.group(1)` and set our entire "cleaned url" to it:
`cleaned_url = re.search('rs--(.*)--plain', url).group(1)`

And now we only "google.com" in our cleaned_url.

This assumes "rs--" and "--plain" are *always* in the url.

**Updated to handle any letters on either side of --:**

```
import re

url = 'po--google.com--plain'
cleaned_url = re.search('[A-z]+--(.*)--[A-z]+', url).group(1)
print(cleaned_url)
```

This will handle anything that has letters before -- and after -- and get only the url in the middle. What that does is check *any* letters on either side of -- regardless of how many letters are there. This will allow queries with letters that match that regular expression so long as --myurl.com-- letters exist before the first "--" and after the second "--"

A great resource for working on regex is [regex101](https://regex101.com/)

Comment: Above code works fine for one url and rest of those are throwing error. The other urls         kl--twitter.com--nglk , pl--bigrock.com--sshm ...etc

Answer (score 0):

You can use [replace function in python](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_replace.htm).

```
>>> val = "rs--google.com--plain"
>>> newval =val.replace("rs--","").replace("--plain","")
>>> newval
'google.com'
```